# How can I make this Join in F#?

Tags: .net, linq, lambda, f#

I have a lambda join in C# which looks like this:

```cs
int[] arrX = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] arrY = { 3, 4, 5 };

var res = arrX.Join(arrY, x => x, y => y, (x, y) => x);
```

After execution res contains 3 which is common for both arrays.

I want to make the exact same lambda join in F#, and try:

```
let arrX = [| 1; 2; 3 |]
let arrY = [| 3; 4; 5 |]

let res = arrX.Join(fun arrY, fun x -> x, fun y -> y, fun (x, y) -> x)
```

But the compiler says:

*Unexpected symbol ',' in lambda expression. Expected '->' or other token.*

The error is the comma after the first parameter arrY.

Can you tell me how I can get it to work (as a lambda expression)?

Comment: In your particular instance, `System.Linq.Enumerable.Intersect(arrX, arrY)` needs no function delegates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this will work for me in F#-interactive (and is the direct translation from your C# code):

```
open System
open System.Linq

let arrX = [| 1; 2; 3 |]
let arrY = [| 3; 4; 5 |]

let res = arrX.Join(arrY, Func<_,_>(id), Func<_,_>(id), (fun x _ -> x))
```

after executing `res` will look like this:

```
> res;;
val it : Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int> = seq [3]
```

## remarks

if you like you can write

```
let res = arrX.Join(arrY, (fun x -> x), (fun x -> x), fun x _ -> x)
```

as @RCH proposed too

Comment: I'm wondering whether I find `(fun x -> x)` more readable than `Func<_, _>(id)`

Comment: if you like - why not. I guess it depends on your taste - you could even do `let res = let id = Func<_,_>(fun x -> x) in arrX.Join(arrY, id, id, fun x y -> x)` ;)

Comment: Yes, why not... My F# taste is still evolving, so I welcome every opportunity for improvement :-)

Comment: What somewhat baffles me about this code it that id in it self "should"have been enough... at least thats what I thought:
let res = arrX.Join(arrY, id, id, (fun x _ -> x))

but again I see that this will make it less generic or whatever... and its probably another subject/question for explaining why that is not sufficient.

Comment: F# will only implicitly transform `fun x -> ...` into `Func<_,_>`

Comment: @CarstenKönig Ahh... Of course. Was somewhat temporarily (hopefully!) reading challenged there. fun != Func obviously ;-) thx...

Answer (score 1):

Note that there are at least two ways to do this using the F# core lib.

```
let arrX = [| 1; 2; 3 |]
let arrY = [| 3; 4; 5 |]

//method 1 (does not preserve order)
let res1 = Set.intersect (set arrX) (set arrY)

//method 2
let res2 = 
    query { 
        for x in arrX do
        join y in arrY on (x = y)
        select x
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

May I boldly suggest the following:

```
open System
open System.Linq

let arrX = [| 1; 2; 3 |]
let arrY = [| 3; 4; 5 |]

let res = Set.intersect (Set.ofArray arrX) (Set.ofArray arrY) |> Set.toArray
```

or if going for some total "obfuscation style":

```
let res' = arrX |> Set.ofArray |> Set.intersect <| (Set.ofArray <| arrY) |> Set.toArray
```

I guess the res'-version is not recommended...

:-)